# How to connect Tableau to Vertica 6.1 database

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, vertica

I want to connect to HP Vertica from Tableau so that I can visualize directly from Tableau.

Can t find the ODBC driver for Vertica database 6.1
Says coming soon but nothing on the downloads tab since November 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MAC**:
I found the 6.1 driver at https://vertica.hpwsportal.com/catalog.html#/Product/%7B%22productId%22%3A%22762%22%7D/Show

--- list of recommended drivers for Vertica versions can be found at http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/drivers-vertica

1. I put the driver in the location /Library/ODBC/
2. Download TableauDrivers.dmg  from http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers
3. DONOT forget to rename the folder vertica-odbc-6.1.3-0.64.mac to vertica
4. Use the Tableau Vertica Configure.pkg to configure
5. Restart
6. Add server connection details in tableau

Viola!